# How to install old commit / revision in IntelliJ Git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In TortoiseHG GUI, I have the possibility to install old revision / commit. Now I am working with Intellij and asking myself how to do this in intelliJ Git?

Comment: What do you man by "install"?

Answer (score 0):

If by "install" you mean checkout an old revision, that would be the [checkout dialog box](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/svn-checkout-options-dialog.html), also visible when you want to [switch branches](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/checking-out-%28switching-between-branches%29.html):

[image: https://www.jetbrains.com/img/webhelp/git_branch_checkout.png]